# Updating Cell Value (JTable)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I'm having a problem while updating cell value of the JTable. What i want to do is after selection of a particular cell from the JTable, i should be able to edit and the action must reflect the database at the back end. I'm using HSQL. My table has 4 columns with one PK.
Kindly give me an alternative and/or provide me with some code by replacing the * s. I'm new just a beginner.

```
d_view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //----action listener of a button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent po) {
        try {
            Connection connec;
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            connec = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/","SA", "");
            java.sql.Statement stt=connec.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stt.executeQuery("select * from DepReg");//----------TO VIEW DATA IN TABULAR FORMAT
            ResultSetMetaData rt=rs.getMetaData();
            int cols=rt.getColumnCount();
            String c[] =new String[cols];
            for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
                c[i]=rt.getColumnName(i+1);
                dm.addColumn(c[i]);
            }
              Object row[]=new Object[cols];
                while(rs.next()){
                     for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
                            row[i]=rs.getString(i+1);
                        }
                    dm.addRow(row);
                }
                table.setModel(dm);
                connec.close();
            }
        catch (Exception ty) {}
    }
});//--------HERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
        int rows=tme.getFirstRow();
        int colms=tme.getColumn();
        TableModel model=(TableModel)tme.getSource();
        String colname=model.getColumnName(colms);
        Object data=model.getValueAt(rows, colms);
//*********EDIT/REPLACE THE CODE ***************//
        try {
            Connection connec;
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            connec = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/","SA", "");
            java.sql.Statement stt=connec.createStatement();
//-----------I WILL INCLUDE AN UPDATE STATEMENT OVER HERE BASED ON THE VALUE SELECTED
        }
        catch (Exception ae) {}
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Database connections should not happen on the Event Dispatch Thread. They are simply too slow. Move that to a background thread. See the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info
- Not completely clear to me whether you are already capable of editing your table, but if not, this is achieved by making sure in the `TableModel` that the `isCellEditable` method returns `true` for the cells you want to be editable, and that you have set a `TableCellEditor` on your `JTable`
- Instead of adding a `TableModelListener` to update your database I would move that logic to a custom `TableModel`. Every time the `setValueAt` method is called, you know changes have been made. You can then update the database (again, not on the Event Dispatch Thread).
- If the database can be updated from other places as well, you probably will want to poll the database at certain moments in time to update your `TableModel` to reflect the latest state of the database. Make sure you do the polling on a worker thread. Then you can either create a brand new `TableModel` on the worker thread, and replace the `TableModel` of the table on the Event Dispatch Thread. Or you can update the existing model on the EDT (do not forget to fire events, or if your model extends from `DefaultTableModel`/`AbstractTableModel` you can use the available API).

I also recommend reading the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes i can edit cells and select an entire row as well...also, is there an alternate method to get the latest state of the database? like using timers (which will check and/or update JTable after few secs)??